# CSS - Best practice for larger margin between all elements but smaller between same elements

Tags: css

Let's say I want to have 2em vertical distance between all elements (p, blockquote, dl, form, ol, ul, pre, table, etc) on a page.

So I throw a `margin-bottom:2em;` on all the necessary elements.  Great.

Then I see that several `P` tags, that come right after each other, look too far apart, and I'd like them to have 1.5em, while keeping the 2em between all the other elements.

What's the most elegant way to do it, while sticking with the we're-going-to-govern-margins-by-only-using-the-bottom-margin concept?

The selector `p+p` would apply a bottom margin to all in the `p` "list" **except** the first one.  Note that it would also put that 1.5 margin on the last `p`, which should not have the small margin, but the larger 2em bottom margin.

I also tried the `:last-child` selector, by putting the small margin value on the bottom of all `p` tags first, then using `p:last-child` to set that last paragraph to the larger 2em bottom margin.  This sounded great, but it didn't actually make that change to the last `p` in the grouping.

> Note that I could switch to governing margin by the top margin, in
>   which case `p+p` would be very elegant to control the spacing between
>   `p` tags.  However, then you have extra spacing at the top (of other elements like h1, etc) sometimes
>   and have to overcome that.  I haven't studied this long enough to know
>   for sure that `margin-bottom` is the best, but it's what I'm going
>   with for now.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding out why the `last-child` selector didn't work.  It was because all the Ps and OLs and other elements were all siblings in the body element, so the browser didn't actually know that the last P in that section was the last-child.

**I wrapped the grouping of Ps in a `<div>` tag and the `last-child` started working.**  Because then, the `last-child` operator was not working with the `body` element, but the last child of that `div`.

So this was the relevant CSS that made me happy...

```
p { margin: 0em 0em 1em;} // the small margin between P tags
p:last-child {margin-bottom: 2em;} // the large margin
```